# How long will it take for a Postgres Flexible Read replica to be promoted to primary server?

Tags: database, postgresql

How long will it take for a Postgres Flexible Read replica to be promoted to primary server. What all factors does the promotion time depend on like the amount of data in the replica?

Need to know if there is a specific time for the promotion to happen, so that I can decide on how long it should take for the failover DNS TTL.

Comment: Start with the documentation and your configuration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-high-availability